# Raspberry PI multiple ethernet server listener

Tags: c, sockets, raspberry-pi, ethernet

I have a simple TCP server listener program running on the third generation raspberry pi. The PI has two ethernet ports:

eth0:-

ip: 10.0.0.100

Bcast: 10.255.255.255

Subnet mask: 255.0.0.0

eth1:-

ip: 10.0.0.110

Bcast: 10.255.255.255

Subnet mask: 255.0.0.0

My program must listen on both IP addresses on specific ports (code below). However, when I attempt to connect to to either of the ip addresses i can't. But if i remove an ethernet cable from the PI and only have the one, then I can connect to that specific IP. Not sure why this is happening.

```
void *Listener1();
void *Listener2();

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL,&Listener1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL,&Listener2, NULL);
    sleep(50);
    return 0;
}
void *Listener1()
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd;
     socklen_t clilen;
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        puts("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.100");
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(12346);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              puts("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,1);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                 &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) 
          puts("ERROR on accept");
     else
        puts("Client connected!");

     close(newsockfd);
     close(sockfd);
     return 0; 
}
void *Listener2()
{
    puts("hi)");
     int sockfd, newsockfd;
     socklen_t clilen;
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        puts("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.110");
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(12345);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              puts("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,1);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                 &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) 
          puts("ERROR on accept");
     else
        puts("Client connected!");

     close(newsockfd);
     close(sockfd);
     return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Your code exhibits undefined behavior due to `Listener1()` and `Listener2()` not being of the correct type for the third argument of `pthread_create()`.

Comment: Really? I don't get any errors when its running, just can't seem to get the two ip addresses

Comment: I've just noticed that the IP addresses for the same device are within the same range, Changed the 2nd to 192.168.x.x and its fine now (y)